# Angular 2 - directive that insjects a component inside, not after

Tags: angular, templates, directive

I want to have a div beeing added inside the tag that has my 'tooltip' directive

but it is happened AFTER the tag instead of inside

so I tried to use templateRef, but there is nothing in my tag so using it returns an error, "No templateRef or something"

```
@Directive({    selector: '[tooltip]'    })
export class TooltipDirective implements OnDestroy {
...

  @Input() set tooltip(caption: any) {
    this.caption=caption;
  }

  @HostListener('mouseenter')
  onMouseEnter(): void {

    if (!this.hasView) {
      //this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);

      const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(TooltipComponent);
      const menuItemComponentRef = this.viewContainer.createComponent(factory);

      menuItemComponentRef.instance.caption = this.caption;

      menuItemComponentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
      this.hasView = true;
    }
  }
}
```

thanks

Comment: come on nobody ?

Comment: please delete this thread